# how to declare private memory in kernel part using opencl in c

Tags: c, opencl

MY question is when coding the kernel part i don't want my code to run on global memory and want to run it on private memory for speed but the problem M facing is i really don't know how to declare private memory and assign it with the global thread id so can anyone help me in terms of code or with an example??

Comment: _want to run it on private memory for speed_.....could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: All the memory being used in the kernel is private, unless it comes as part of the argument.

Comment: actually my requiement is read a single password from dict file which contains million passwords..so i want to take a single password run it in private memory and then copy back to the global memory and send back to the host side to read  the passowrd..im not able to get how can i do??